# Getting Multiple Lists and displaying them to the View

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, list, linq

I have a system where I enter in *other*, *employee*, and *dealer* information as such (there is more fields but trying to keep it simple).

```
+----+---------+--------------+------------+-------+
| ID |  itemId | memberTypeId | MemberType | price |
+----+---------+--------------+------------+-------+
|  1 |     202 |            2 | employee   |  2.00 |
|  2 |     202 |            3 | dealer     |  3.00 |
|  3 |     101 |            1 | other      |  4.00 |
+----+---------+--------------+------------+-------+
```

I’m trying to make the Update functionality on my site. When I make a DB call based on the ItemId to get everything.

**Here is such code from helper class:**

```
public class Item { 
 public static List<ItemOption> GetItemOpttions(long itemID)
 {           
  using (DBContext context = new DBContext())
  {
    List<ItemOptionDTO> ItemOptionsDto = (
        from I in context.ItemOptions
        where I.ItemID == itemID
        select new ItemOptionDTO
        {
            ItemID = I.ItemID,
            MemberTypeId = I.MemberTypeId
            MemberType = I.MemberType,
            Price = I.Price, 
                                                        
        }).ToList();           

    return ItemOptionsDto;
  }
 }
}
```

So, when I get the data and store it in a list. It’s either one row of data or two rows based on how it was saved. The option “Other” will always be saved into the DB as one row of data as where “employee and dealer” will be saved as two separate row sharing the same ItemId. When called the number of rows will vary based on each item created at an earlier date/time.

I am trying to get this info back to the controller and send it to the View showing the correct values that might get updated. Here is what I have in the controller. I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing this or if there is a better way.

Also to add that the if the item was saved as an employee and dealer it will leave the other list empty/null. I don't think I can do this because it will cause a *null exception error*

**This is what I have so far in the controller:**

```
public ActionResult UpdateItem(long itemID) {
 List<ItemOptionDTO> itemOptionDto = Item.GetItemOpttions(itemID);

  var other = itemOptionDto.Where(x => x.MemberTypeId == 1).FirstOrDefault();
  var employee = itemOptionDto.Where(x => x.MemberTypeId == 2).FirstOrDefault();
  var dealer = itemOptionDto.Where(x => x.MemberTypeId == 3).FirstOrDefault();

  UpdateItemViewModel viewModel = new UpdateItemViewModel(itemID, employee, dealer, option)
   {
    ItemId = option.ItemId, 
    MemberType = option.MemberType, 
    Price = other.price

    ItemId = employee.ItemId, 
    MemberType = employee.MemberType, 
    Price = employee.price

    ItemId = dealer.ItemId, 
    MemberType = dealer.MemberType, 
    Price = dealer.price
   };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Let me know if there is anything else I can provide.

Comment: It looks to me like the code for the viewModel will not compile. I don't understand what you're doing there.

Comment: How can a method that takes only the ID of an item that needs updating, hope to update anything about the item? Surely it needs to take new values too?